# fireEvent.click() (form fireEvent) vs element.click() (from JSDOM)

Tags: click, jsdom, testing-library, user-event

Context: I'm using Testing Library and trying to understand some of the underlying mechanisms.

As JSDOM already provides the handling of the "click" event, I was wondering:

- Is there a difference between these two ways of managing the event?
- If not, why fireEvent redefines this event?

If there are differences, I would like to understand what they are and when to use one tool or the other.

(For the second question, I have an idea but I want to confirm:
fireEvent provides a global and unified interface for generating events. And the click is a natural part of it.)

Comment: Stack Overflow is about solving problems. Please be more specific on what's the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTMLElement.click` triggers a click event

`fireEvent.click` triggers a click event with event properties of your choice (e.g. `detail: 2`)

Straight from the [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events#fireeventeventname):

> Note
>
> Most projects have a few use cases for fireEvent, but the majority of the time you should probably use [@testing-library/user-event](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event).

`userEvent.click` triggers all events that should happen in a browser if a user clicks an element (`hover`, `pointerdown`, etc.)

Comment: With your answer, I understand that `HTMLElement.click` (managed by JSDOM) and `fireEvent.click` (without specifying any particular event properties) are similar. Is this correct?

Comment: Roughly, yes.
It also wraps the dispatched event if you are using one of the framework specific libraries. E.g. `act()` if you are using `@testing-library/react`

Comment: Oh! Yes! It wraps events with `act()`. Thank you, good point.

Answer (score 1):

Your guess it right. They even say so in their docs. It's just a "Convenience methods for firing DOM events."
You can see a full map of events (click also) here:
https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/blob/master/src/event-map.js